# Create or Modify an Eclipse Plugin from a repository (e.g. SVN)

Tags: java, svn, eclipse-plugin

i have a project  in SVN, with several plugins for Eclipse.
i want to modify one of these plugins, so i check out the folders of this plugin.
When i want to export the modified plugin as a deployable plugin, i keep getting errors that there are Java projects missing.

[image]

The whole project has a red exclamation mark.

[image]

How can one modify a plugin that is retrieved from a repository like SVN?

Comment: You need to have the complete set of projects so that Eclipse can build things properly.

Comment: i did that too, but when i right click on that specific Plugin to export it as a deployable Plugin, there is no Plugin listed, that i can choose from.